# fade in out UWP with asynch method to populate the Xaml control

Tags: c#, asynchronous, win-universal-app

I am missing something there can anyone help?
In myFlipview I am trying to display messages and I would like to make invisible the moment the flipview goes to his next item

```
  <FlipView x:Name="fvWelcome" VerticalAlignment="Center"   >



        <FlipView.Triggers>


            <EventTrigger>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="fvWelcome" 
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FlipView.Opacity)"
                                      AutoReverse="False"
                                      From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:4" 
                                      RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </FlipView.Triggers>

        <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemsPanel>

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate >

            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>




                    <TextBox x:Name="GuestNameTextBox"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Margin="252,0,0,0"
                             Foreground="White"
                             FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                             BorderBrush="#FF1F4E79" 
                             BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="84"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" 
                             Background="#FF1F4E79" 
                            >

                        <TextBox.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                          Storyboard.TargetName="GuestNameTextBox" 
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Opacity)"
                                      AutoReverse="False"
                                      From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:4" 
                                      RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </TextBox.Triggers>

                    </TextBox>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

in My mainPage c# side I've got this

```
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private DispatcherTimer _welcomeTimer;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            StartWelcomeGuest();
        }
        private void StartWelcomeGuest()
        {

            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            myList.Add("Un");
            myList.Add("deux");
            myList.Add("trois");
            myList.Add("quatre");
            myList.Add("cinq");
            myList.Add("six");
            myList.Add("sept");
            fvWelcome.ItemsSource = myList;
            fvWelcome.SelectedIndex = 0;


            _welcomeTimer = new DispatcherTimer()
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)
            };

            _welcomeTimer.Tick += __welcomeTimer_Tick;
            _welcomeTimer.Start();
        }

        private void __welcomeTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {



            if (fvWelcome.SelectedIndex < fvWelcome.Items.Count - 1)
            {


                fvWelcome.SelectedIndex++;



            }

            else
            {
                //_welcomeFade.Stop();
                _welcomeTimer.Stop();

            }


        }
    }
```

I've got the fade in /out effect synchronized with the visbility of the fliView and the textbox how can I do the same with an async method to populate my FlipView

```
private async Task<List<string>> GuestGreetings()
        {


            IList<ServiceNameGuest.MyObject> myvalue = await ServiceNameGuest.GetBriefingsByDateAndCenter
                                                 (new DateTime(2016, 03, 14), new DateTime(2016, 03, 18), "Brussels");

            foreach (var item in myvalue)
            {


                ListName.Add(item.BriefingTitle);


            }

            ListName = ListName.Distinct().ToList();
            if (App.AddedGuest.Count>0)
            { 
                foreach (var item in App.AddedGuest)
                {
                    if(item!="")
                    ListName.Add( item);

               };
            }
            return ListName;

        }
        private async void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {

                fvWelcome.ItemsSource = await GuestGreetings();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            this.StartWelcomeGuest();

        }
```

just because to populate my flipview I used an asnych method ,I am losing my fade in/out effect, I thought I could store my data in DB but there must be an easier way do you have an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I understood the problem, as I was dealing with seconds I had to synchronize with my storyboard,
*give a name to the storyboard :FlpVOpacity

```
<FlipView x:Name="fvWelcome" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF1F4E79"  >



            <FlipView.Triggers>

                <!-- Theme animations like this can use the default behavior like
             this example or you could use properties like BeginTime and 
             Duration to tweak when and how quickly the animation occures. 
             If you want more control over a fade animation (e.g. just partial
             fade), you will need to use DoubleAnimation to animate the Opacity 
             property of the element you want to fade in or out. -->

                <EventTrigger>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="FlpVOpacity">

                            <DoubleAnimation
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="fvWelcome" 
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FlipView.Opacity)"
                                          AutoReverse="True"
                                          From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:4" 
                                          RepeatBehavior="1x" />
                        </Storyboard>                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </FlipView.Triggers>
```

then just where I am going to the next item in my flipView,i just used seek to my storyboard  FlpVOpacity.Seek(TimeSpan.Zero);

```
private void __welcomeTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {



            if (fvWelcome.SelectedIndex < fvWelcome.Items.Count - 1)
            {


                fvWelcome.SelectedIndex++;
                FlpVOpacity.Seek(TimeSpan.Zero);

            }

            else
            {
                //_welcomeFade.Stop();
                _welcomeTimer.Stop();
                StartVideos();
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a static variable to store my guestname instead of db as I thaught initially